# Why rotate using python not work in blender 2.6?

Tags: python, blender

I'm new to blender.
Did I missed something?

however type: `bpy.data.objects['Suzanne'].rotation_euler[2] = 1.25` in console window will make model to rotate.

But following code not rotate the model at all. Why?

```
import bpy
import math

cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
origin = bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']

step_count = 5
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].cycles.samples=10

for step in range(0, step_count):
    r = math.pi * step * (360.0 / step_count) / 180.0
    print(r)
    origin.rotation_euler[2] = r       # seems not work!
    fn = '/tmp/mokey_%02d.jpg' % step
    print(fn)
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = fn
    bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly fine. I've just verified it using Blender 2.71

However, rotation in blender has a small pitfall: There are multiple possible rotation-modes in blender. Modifying euler angles, won't have an effect, as long as a different rotation-mode is activated for the particular object.

You can enforce the right rotation-mode using the `rotation_mode` member (see [the documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_mode) for a full list of possible rotation-modes).
In your example, you probably want to use the xyz-Euler angles:

```
origin.rotation_mode = 'XYZ' # Force using euler angles
```

Here is the workaround integrated into your example:

```
import bpy
import math

cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
origin = bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']

step_count = 5
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].cycles.samples=10

origin.rotation_mode = 'XYZ' # Force the right rotation mode

for step in range(0, step_count):
    r = math.pi * step * (360.0 / step_count) / 180.0
    print(r)
    origin.rotation_euler[2] = r
    fn = '/home/robert/mokey_%02d.jpg' % step
    print(fn)
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = fn
    bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
```